# What does the "A+" stand for in "Promise/A+"?

Tags: javascript, promise

What does the "A+" stand for in "Promise/A+"? I tried looking online, but I keep getting programming examples or introductions to promises. Not really what I was looking for. As a note: I found the Promise/A+ from https://promisesaplus.com/

Comment: I think this is just the name of an Organisation.

Comment: Take a look at the spec. There's Promises A/C/D, so thre are different types.

Comment: i see, that makes the most sense then. I had no clue there was different types!

Comment: @wheaties if you post it as an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: @JemiloII, "this is a legitimate question, downvoting because you don't know the answer is just stilly" Your initial question did not show much research effort given that the answer can be found within the page that you linked to.

Comment: do you really want every google search I've made for the past half hour and every site I searched for? All I was finding was examples about C code or A+ certification. To be honest, I didn't know how to search for the answer to this one. Even searching Promise/A I was getting similar results.

Answer (score 5):

From [the Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/)

> Historically, Promises/A+ clarifies the behavioral clauses of the earlier [Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) proposal, extending it to cover de facto behaviors and omitting parts that are underspecified or problematic.

The A+ refers to the extension of the Promises/A spec.

Answer (score 2):

So @wheaties helped me with finding the answer, if he posts an answer, I'll switch to accept his, in the meantime I'll post this.

So the A+ is just the proposal name for a promise implementation. Out of what I was able to find from what @wheaties said, I also found one more.

Promises/A, Promises/B, Promises/C, Promises/D, Promises/KISS

you can learn more about these from the common.js wiki http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises

Comment: Yes, those are variants of the Promises proposals, sort of version if you want to call it that way. Promise/A+ builds upon Promise/A version of the proposal, hence the plus.

Answer (score 0):

From [promisesaplus.com](https://promisesaplus.com/):

> An open standard for sound, interoperable JavaScript promises—by implementers, for implementers.
>
> A promise represents the eventual result of an asynchronous operation. The primary way of interacting with a promise is through its then method, which registers callbacks to receive either a promise’s eventual value or the reason why the promise cannot be fulfilled.
>
> This specification details the behavior of the then method, providing an interoperable base which all Promises/A+ conformant promise implementations can be depended on to provide. As such, the specification should be considered very stable. Although the Promises/A+ organization may occasionally revise this specification with minor backward-compatible changes to address newly-discovered corner cases, we will integrate large or backward-incompatible changes only after careful consideration, discussion, and testing.
>
> Historically, Promises/A+ clarifies the behavioral clauses of the earlier Promises/A proposal, extending it to cover de facto behaviors and omitting parts that are underspecified or problematic.
>
> Finally, the core Promises/A+ specification does not deal with how to create, fulfill, or reject promises, choosing instead to focus on providing an interoperable then method. Future work in companion specifications may touch on these subjects.

Comment: This explains what the `+` stands for but not the `A`. The question was about `A+`, so both `A` and `+`…